# Hide overlayed/embedded rtmp stream when rtmp input is having connection issues or is reconnecting

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am running ffmpeg like this, to overlay a picture with a video (but could be also a video and a video of course):

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i /tmp/bild.jpg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/other/stream -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=720:-1[fg];[0:v][fg]overlay=(W-w)/3:(H-h)/3:shortest=1" -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -b:a 128k -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/publish/camera1
```

The reconnect with reconnect_at_eof works fine, but while the second input is unavailable, the last frame of the input will just get stuck on the screen.

Is there any way to change the behavior so that ffmpeg hides the unavailable stream while it is reconnecting and unhides it once available?